# Permanently disable IPv6, for a given interface?

Tags: linux, ipv6, network-interface

I'm looking to permanently disable IPv6 on a specific interface because it's broken and [my question on Superuser to fix it](https://superuser.com/questions/882695/) is dead so how can I go about doing that? I've added `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` but it doesn't work for some reason. At the moment I just use the sysctl command every time I turn on my PC to disable it.

Comment: Do you see value in sysctl.conf persistent after reboo....you can also put `up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.$IFACE.disable_ipv6=1` in the /etc/interface file

Comment: @Miline if you're asking if the entry stays there after reboot yes it does.

Comment: your problem is syntax in the sysctl.conf file you need to use the syntax `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1` instead of `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6=1`

Comment: @mchid does that space really matter?

Comment: @Scoopta yes, I believe so. If you look at the default options in that file they all use the same syntax and I believe I've seen this issue before with setting swappiness.

Comment: @mchid it didn't work with the space either.

Comment: @Scoopta this is exactly why I disable ipv6 at the kernel, no other option has ever worked for me.

Comment: @mchid I'm a bit disappointed considering I have to do a complete disable of IPv6 and I can't just get that one interface. I did try using `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6=1` in grub but it didn't work.

Comment: check out http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/47118.html it looks like you might have to set /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/disable_ipv6 to 1 as well but who knows if that will survive across reboot.

Comment: @mchid I tested that however it does not survive a reboot.

Comment: @mchid the only thing that works is using `ipv6.disable=1` at kernel level but I wish I could specify an interface.

Comment: I tried adding net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1 to /etc/sysctl.conf and it seems to work for me; running `ifconfig` shows no ipv6 address and `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/dis*` shows 1 but `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/dis*` shows 0. but I also have it commented out in `/etc/hosts` see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPv6#Disable_functionality

Comment: I asked you a question in regard to your [su] question but you never answered it. So I never came back to look at it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did answer it.

Comment: Not completely!

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry :( I'll add a comment to try to more completely answer it

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have listed my exact networking scenario on Superuser. Sorry for not being clear enough the first time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, edit /etc/default/grub and find the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

and change the line to say this instead (this will disable ipv6 completely):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

alternatively, to leave the ipv6 stack functional but to disable assignment of ipv6 addresses you can use the following option instead:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable_ipv6=1"
```

Finally, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot to apply the changes.

This will disable ipv6 at the kernel level so that it is never enabled from the get-go.

---

Also, after making the following changes to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Run the following command to apply the changes:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

---

Finally, if using the option to disable ipv6 in sysctl.conf, you need to also make sure ipv6 is commented out in /etc/hosts. See here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPv6#Disable_functionality

Comment: This disables ipv6 completely. Not only on the broken interface.

Comment: @michas using `ipv6.disable_ipv6=1` instead of `ipv6.disable=1` does not completely disable ipv6, it just prevents ipv6 address assignment. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPv6#Disable_functionality

Answer (score 0):

Neither the grub nor the sysctl solution worked for me. My guess is that systemd reenabled ipv6 during boot.

So I changed systemd to only configure ipv4 for my `en*` devices:

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/network/en-all.network
```

```
[Match]
Name=en*
[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv4
```