# How can I disable IPv6 with the "ip" command?

Tags: ip, ipv6

I need to disable the usage/assignemnt of the IPv6, I tried creating the /etc/sysctl.d/40-ipv6.conf file and adding the relative settings, I've also tried editing the GRUB adding the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable_ipv6=1"
```

And after `sudo update-grub` and rebooting the system, IPv6 still be used by my eth card.

Is there permanent way I can disable IPv6 using the "ip" linux command?

Comment: Warning: Disabling IPv6 is not recommended. This will cause some services to fail and you to be unable to communicate with some Internet hosts.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Good point..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following configuration lines belong in the file, `/etc/sysctl.d/40-ipv6.conf` to disable IPv6 on all interfaces.

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Which Linux are we talking about? The GRUB configuration method looks something like the following configuration in, perhaps, `/etc/default/grub`.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1 rhgb quiet"
```

After changing the GRUB configuration, one must reinstall GRUB and reboot.

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
shutdown -r now
```

Later, check to see that the configuration was successful.

```
ip addr show | grep net6
```

Or, to simply prevent the IPv6 module from binding to the IPv6 networking stack, add the line below to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (or a different file name according to the existing directory/file structure):

```
options ipv6 disable=1
```

Then reboot.

This will allow the loading of the IPv6 module in order to satisfy any other modules that depend on it while disabling support for the IPv6 protocol.

In a RedHat-based OS, one could use the following directive in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

```
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
```

Answer (score 0):

If this solution does not work for you, try disabling the interface with systemd.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/730202/46158

```
[Match]
Name=en*
[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv4
```